# How to make my python unscrambling code more efficient?

Tags: python, python-itertools

My Code

```
from itertools import permutations

original = str(input('What word would you like to unscramble?: '))

gen = []
for bob in permutations(original):
    gen.append(''.join(bob))



inputFile = open('dic.txt', 'r')
compare = inputFile.read().split('\n')
inputFile.close()

rondo = set(john for john in gen if john in compare)

for magic in rondo:
    print(magic)
```

I use it to unscramble words by finding all possible permutations of a word and comparing each permutation to a dictionary to find real words, and then returning those real words. However, going over eight letters causes an error as I run out of ram before the program can finish and words with seven or eight letters take a long time to unscramble. I would like to know if there is a way to make my code able to run faster with longer words as well as a way to increase the maximum word length. I'm using Python 3 and am a bit of a beginner if it matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of appending all of the permutations to a list, you should just iterate over them directly.

```
set(''.join(john) for john in permutations(original) if ''.join(john) in compare)
```

or

```
set(john for john in (''.join(bob) for bob in permutations(original)) if john in compare)
```

A better way of finding the solution would be to create a signature of the word either by creating a map from letter to count or by sorting the letters. Then you would only need to compare the signature of the scrambled word to the signatures from the word list.

```
words = {}
for word in compare:
    key = ''.join(sorted(word))
    if key in words:
        words[key].add(word)
    else:
        words[key] = {word}

return words[''.join(sorted(original))]
```

Comment: Thank you! I understand what you're saying, but could you possibly please give me a demonstration as I'm not completely sure how to do this.

Comment: You can make a signature by sorting the letters as follows. Scan through your current dictionary file that has one word per line and create a new file that has two words on each line: the original word with the letters sorted alphabetically, followed by the original word. Then to unscramble a word, you just sort it and search for the sorted version in your new file. You may be able to store the new double word list in memory as a Python `dict` with the sorted word as the key and the original version as the value. If not, you can rapidly search through a sorted file using bisection.

Comment: This is good, but I would still recommend that the asker of the question understands and make use of generators in the code, as per my answer.

Comment: @CaptainWhippet I had also included your answer in mine. However, I didn't separate it out clearly, which is why you probably missed it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a generator instead of list:

```
gen = ( ''.join(bob) for bob in permutations(original))
```

This will save you memory usage.

There's a good discussion on the use of generators vs. list comprehensions here: [Generator Expressions vs. List Comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47789/generator-expressions-vs-list-comprehension)

There's also another good discussion here: [Understanding Generators in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756096/understanding-generators-in-python)